# Ruby: Calling a self.method from find_by object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, self

I'm trying to call the self.method after getting the object using a find_by(id)

Code in the route creation of app.get():

```
userFound = Models::Persistence::User.find_by(:auth_id => authid)
result = Models::Persistence::User.new
result = userFound
puts result.class
puts userFound.class 
return result.to_json
```

The self.method function is defined in the Models::Persistence::User. Can anyone tell me why the self.transformToApiValue() doen't get invoked? 
Things I tried:
Ran the code in Debug more to see if the self.method is being reached at all. Tunrs out it doesn't.

Do let me know if it's unclear/ I need to post more code snippets.

Edit1: The self function in the user models simply removes the oid etc for the client to view

```
  def self.transformToApiValue(key, val)
    val = super(key, val)
    if (key == 'useractivity')
      newVal = []
      val.each { |useractivity|
        if useractivity != 'course'
          newBlock = Models::Persistence::Useractivity.parseForClient(useractivity)
          newVal.push(newBlock)
        end
      }
      val = newVal
    end
    return val
  end
```

The above function allows customization of useractivity attribute in the JSON when converting it to client values.

Comment: Sorry but why was I downvoted?

Comment: I can't make head or tail of your question - among other things you ask "why this happens" but you haven't said what "this" is

Comment: Sure. I will edit it once more. I am working on a huge module so it became slightly difficult to post code without any context. But, I'll edit it right away.

Comment: To put things another way you've posted some code but nowhere do you say what the problem is: what is the question here?

Comment: I've just made some edits. Does it make sense now? My issue is that the self.method is never reached when I create or save any object of User model.

Comment: Why should transformToApiValue be called?

Comment: Because when a request is sent to the route, the method should be invoked as the route is being created with the User Model and the self method belongs to that model.

Comment: I don't see you calling `transformToApiValue` anywhere, so why should it be called? If it's supposed to be called implicitly somewhere (maybe `to_json`?) that's a Rails feature. I added the ruby-on-rails tag.

Comment: Routes map urls to controllers - they don't call models (at least that's not how rails behaves out of the box)

Comment: Can you post a snippet with a code that invokes `transformToApiValue` method?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are assuming a little too much magic on rails side.

the self.method is a class method.  That means to call it you must run this somewhere in your controller or another model explicitly

```
Models::Persistence::User.transformToApiValue(your_key, your_val)
```

Based on what you mentioned this is probably not what you are looking for though.  You are wanting to do a callback that will set the value before it is saved.  So in your user model, you will add

```
before_save :transform_api_value
```

and then in the same model you will define that

```
def transform_api_value
  attribute_you_are_editing = Models::Persistence::User.transformToApiValue(value_you_are_transforming)
end
```

This will then run your transform before it is saved and save the user attribute properly.  You will have to update your transformToApiValue.  The code was hard to follow when i first read it but I hope this helps you understand the concept.

Wanted to add that there are a few gotchas on here, for instance you may not want to do this on every save, you may want to just do it on create.  I would recommend reading the callbacks guide to decide how your business logic will fit in this.  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: Just tried the Models::Persistence::User.transformToApiValue(your_key, your_val) call explicitly. The callback requires refactoring many more modules so I'll work on that later. Thanks.